# TypeError: this.$eventBus is not a function at Proxy.mounted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, eventemitter, vue-events

I am doing migration from vue2 to vue3 and because event emitter($on) moved from vue3, I am getting this error. To avoid this I installed tiny-emitter (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-emitter) but error didnt change after I applied it. Here is the version of my application when it was in vue2:

```js
mounted() {
  this.$eventBus().$on('open-dropdown', () => {
    this.isDropOpen = !this.isDropOpen;
  });
}
```

And here is vue3 version:

```js
import emitter from 'tiny-emitter/instance';

export default {
$on: (...args) => emitter.on(...args),
  $once: (...args) => emitter.once(...args),
  $off: (...args) => emitter.off(...args),
  $emit: (...args) => emitter.emit(...args),
mounted() {
    this.$eventBus().$emit('open-dropdown', () => {
      this.isDropOpen = !this.isDropOpen;
    });
  },
}
```

even I added tiny-emitter, like I said I am getting the same error. So what do I do wrong?

Comment: You didn't define $eventBus, so it's undefined. It's unclear why it's supposed to be a function if you use the same instance

Comment: can I go like this instead of eventBus? emitter.on('open-dropdown', function () {
      this. isDropOpen = !this. isDropOpen;
    });

Comment: Yes, that's how it's supposed to used, but an arrow instead of `function () {`